# ExecuteJoinedDataSet but with Where()

Tags: subsonic

I did some searching and see that ExecuteJoinedDataSet will not work with the Where clause in 2.1.  If I want to query a table with WHERE, but want the FK objects values to be bindable is the easiest way to just create a custom class(my table has tons of FK references).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you give us an example of what kind of query you are trying to write?  If you are just trying to return a DataTable without creating a custom class just write your query and use the ExecuteReader which Returns an IDataReader.  The IDataReader is bindable and if you need more you can just load it into a DataTable.

Comment: I am able to do what I wanted to using SubSonic.SqlQuery, Select() and Joins.  I just liked how simple it was to use ExecuteJoinedDataSet to display my FK values in much less code, which unfortunately doesn't recognize the Where clause.  I was hoping there was something similar built in.

Comment: This was a bug in 2.1 (see http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/issues/detail?id=28). It was corrected for 2.2.